# IP address needed to pass to run app on android device

Tags: php, android

I am developing an app in android in which i am making use of json parsing to get data from php file and also sending data to php file from android. This time I am running my app on emulator so I am passing ip address of emulator i.e. 10.0.2.2. Now I want to run that app on android device,so what ip address is needed to passed instead of emulator's address?

Comment: Are you using WAMP for PHP ?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do - can you explain it a bit more? this way, your question seems to broad to me!

Comment: @LordT, It's pretty clear. The OP want to access the webservice through the android mobile (not through emulator) so in that case `10.0.2.2` will not work , the webservice should be accessible through internet.

Comment: Nope, he is referring to the IP address of the emulator - which seems to me like he is connecting to a service running on the emulator?

Comment: I think he is want the possible way to find the IP address of Android device and then send it to webservice

Comment: @MohammadAhmad-yeah u r rite....i want this only

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran-yeah u r rite,webservice shuld b accessible through internet but which ip address should i pass instead of that of emulator.

Comment: @LordT-this time i am connecting to emulator but now i want to run this app on android device. So which address should i pass to connect to webservice?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran-yes i m using wamp server

Comment: Please update the question and tell us exactly, from where to where you want to connect and which ip you are trying to find. Are you connecting from your app to a php service on your Computer? Is that the up you need? Currently, I have to guess this.